# Return type of GROUP BY statement in Room Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to make the following query to my database:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(*) FROM offerings GROUP BY type
```

This query works well with an Sqlite browser. Now I want to use this query in my `Dao`:

```
@Query("SELECT type, COUNT(*) FROM offerings GROUP BY type")
LiveData<Map<String, Integer>> getOfferingsGroupedByType();
```

But I am getting the error: ... **not sure how to convert a cursor to this method's return type**

How can I query a table with 2 columns? --> that is, [type, count(type)] ?

Comment: From Room 2.4, you can convert it to a Map, see the Google Doc:https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#multimap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step #1: Give a name to the count: `SELECT type, COUNT(*) AS count FROM offerings GROUP BY type`

Step #2: Create a Java class with suitable fields:

```java
public class Thingy {
  public String type;
  public int count;
}
```

Step #3: Have your return type from the DAO method use that class:

```java
@Query("SELECT type, COUNT(*) FROM offerings GROUP BY type")
LiveData<List<Thingy>> getOfferingsGroupedByType();
```

I don't recall Room supporting returning a `Map`, so you will need to handle that aspect yourself, either in the observer or via a `MediatorLiveData` that wraps the `LiveData` you get from the DAO and does the conversion.

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick. I wasn't aware that there is a binding between the query and the fields. Thank you!

Comment: awesome trick! I needed to use "COUNT(*) as count" in my select statement to map to the count variable in the return class

Comment: You should include **@ColumnInfo(name = "type")** and **@ColumnInfo(name = "count")** so even after the fields get obfuscated in release build, it should work fine.